# Rails: has_many through table for followers, followings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User model and a user has many followers and following :through connections:

```
has_many :connections
has_many :followers, :through => :connections, :foreign_key => :follower_id, :source => :user, class_name: User
has_many :following, :through => :connections, :foreign_key => :user_id, :source => :user, class_name: User
```

My connection table has a user_id (user being followed) and a follower_id (user who is following).

I can create a new connection:

```
Connection.create(user_id: 1, follower_id: 500)
```

I see that the connection has been created, yet I cannot access this from the respective users:

```
u = User.find(1)
u.followers => []
u.following => []

u = User.find(500)
u.followers => []
u.following => []
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On the first relation you have the source `:user` while you should have it as `:follower`.

**Later edit:**

The above fixes one issue but the complete solution requires two has many connections: one for follwers and one for following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followers_connections, foreign_key: :user_id, class_name: "Connection"
  has_many :following_connections, foreign_key: :follower_id, class_name: "Connection"
  has_many :followers, through: :followers_connections, class_name: "User", source: :follower
  has_many :following, through: :following_connections, class_name: "User", source: :user
end


class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
end


# create some sample data
5.times { User.create }
Connection.create user_id: 1, follower_id: 2
Connection.create user_id: 1, follower_id: 3
Connection.create user_id: 4, follower_id: 1
Connection.create user_id: 5, follower_id: 1

# get followers
User.find(1).followers.pluck(:id) => [2, 3]
# SQL run: SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "connections" ON "users"."id" = "connections"."follower_id" WHERE "connections"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]

# get following
User.find(1).following.pluck(:id) => [4, 5]
# SQL run: SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "connections" ON "users"."id" = "connections"."user_id" WHERE "connections"."follower_id" = ?  [["follower_id", 1]]
```

Comment: Awesome - that's working on the u.followers, but still showing up as blank for u.following. Any idea why?

Comment: User 1 starts following user 2.  When  I call user1.following ==> []. user2.following ==> [user2]

Comment: You will need 2 has_many relations to connections. Post an example above in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Update associations as following, They should work for you.

```
has_many :connections
has_many :followers, through: :connections, class: 'User'
has_many :following, through: :connections, foreign_key: :follower_id, source: :user
```

**Explanation:**
1) when you say **User has_many followers through connections**,
**Rails** expects `user_id` in `connections` table. In our case yes we have `user_id` in `connections` table.
**Rails** expects `follower_id` in connections. In our case yes we have `follower_id` in connections. But here from `follower_id` Rails infers `follower` as model, we don't have any model name `follower`. So we need to mention `class: 'User'` to use for retrieving `followers`.

2) When you say **User has_many following through connections**,
**Rails** expects `user_id` in `connections` table. In our case yes we have `user_id` in connections but we don't want to use this user_id to retrieve `following`, we need `follower_id` to retrieve `following`, so here we need to mention `foreign_key: :follower_id`, so that Rails use `follower_id` as foreign key.
**Rails** expects `following_id` in `connections` table. In our case we don't have `following_id` in `connections` table. So we need to mention `source: :user`, now from this Rails expecting `User` model, which is valid.

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many